# iOS global proxy does not work in some applications

Tags: ios, ssl, wireshark, packet-sniffers, charles-proxy

I have set manual proxy in the Wifi section in the iOS device. It's ok when I using safari, But when I using Whatsapp and some other apps, the requests does not go through the proxy.
I sniffed the packets using Wireshark and it show client connected to the api using the 443 port, But it bypass the proxy.

Answer (score 3):

The proxy configuration on iOS is actually specifically for *HTTP* proxies.

It does not mean that all network traffic is sent via the proxy - only HTTP traffic, like the traffic used to load websites in Safari. Whatsapp's protocol is not standard HTTP (it seems like it uses [a variant of XMPP](https://medium.com/@rajendra_51543/how-whatsapp-works-197bfc6d6b95)) and so in their app they will be using APIs that do not take the HTTP proxy configuration into account.

While most apps will use HTTP for API calls and similar, not all will, so this may apply in other cases too. While it is usually possible in theory to proxy arbitrary TCP protocols via an [HTTP CONNECT tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_method) on a standard HTTP proxy (i.e. whatsapp could support HTTP proxies if they really wanted to) it's totally impossible to proxy UDP or ICMP via a standard HTTP proxy (because CONNECT is always TCP) so this is actually unavoidable for some traffic.